# Doctrine class map inheritance and join

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 2 entities (ProductX and ProductY), herited from Product (inheritance type: JOINED, with Discriminator). 
I need to add a condition on ProductX or productY field. 
But the query builder doesn't show this entities.

I try :`$queryBuilder->leftJoin('App\Entity\ProductX', 'productX', 'WITH', 'o.id = productX.id');`

But in this case, the generated DQL is :

`LEFT JOIN (
    product_x p8_ 
    INNER JOIN product p9_ ON p8_.id = p9_.id
  ) ON (p0_.id = p9_.id)`

instead of :

`LEFT JOIN product_x p8_ ON p0_.id = p8_.id`

Any idea to do that ?

Comment: I don't get which is the problem. Is that it is tranforming left join into inner?

Comment: The problem is performance.
`LEFT JOIN (
    product_x p8_ 
    INNER JOIN product p9_ ON p8_.id = p9_.id
  ) ON (p0_.id = p9_.id)`

take more time than a simple `LEFT JOIN product_x p8_ ON p0_.id = p8_.id`.

I have 8 entites to join.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do something like that I think :

```
$queryBuilder->leftJoin('App\Entity\ProductX', 'productX');
```

This will return something you want, other arguments it's generaly use for custom relationship

More detail here:
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html

I hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks, but not working... Generate only `LEFT JOIN product_x p3_` without ON condition.